# How do i open the internet explorer in maximized state from powerbuilder

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder

we are using the OLE object to call the internet explorer, how do i open them in maximized state by default.
Below are the code

```
ioleInternetExplorer = create oleobject
ioleInternetExplorer.connecttonewobject( "InternetExplorer.Application" )
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
ioleInternetExplorer.fullscreen = TRUE
```

I have not tested this.  A resource for IE methods and properties can be found [here](http://nerds-central.blogspot.com/2007/02/internet-explorer-ole-com-interface-api.html#3.SUMMARY%7Coutline)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
CONSTANT Integer  WM_SYSCOMMAND = 274
CONSTANT UInt  SC_MAXIMIZE   = 61488
//
Send(ioleInternetExplorer.HWND, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0)
```